# How can I manage Azure AD B2C with a service principal from the main directory

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-ad-b2c

We are running Azure AD B2C to authenticate users in our application. We also managed to codify almost everything with Terraform and are pretty happy with it. Now we are attempting to move these manifests under Azure Devops Pipelines and are stuck with access problems.

Azure Pipelines use a dedicated service principal in the main (non B2C) Active Directory to perform its operations. We granted this SP enough permissions within the target subscription to handle Terraform resources. But I cannot find any way to grant this SP any permissions on the B2C directory. I can invite users from the primary directory to the B2C, and it works fine, but SP is an application, not a user.

Is there any way to "invite" an application from the primary directory into the B2C directory?

Comment: Is it not possible to use a different service principal that you create in the B2C tenant? And yes it is technically possible to add that SP in the B2C tenant as well by making it multi-tenant and going through a manually crafted login request. But even then the same access token that the SP uses won't work against both tenants. It would have to authenticate twice anyway and wouldn't really be different from just having an SP in the B2C tenant.

Comment: @juunas, thank you for replying. Creating a different service principal in the B2C tenant is possible, but I wanted to avoid it. That's one more secret to manage and is cumbersome to configure in Terraform. Seems that there is no way around for now.

Comment: Tenants are isolated entities, you should treat them as such in this case.

Comment: what did your final setup look like for this? I am currently stuck trying to manage resources for the B2C tenant and my main AD tenant in the azure devops pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to "invite" an application from the primary directory
> into the B2C directory?

If your app registration support account types is **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)**, you would be able to add the same service principal in your Azure AD B2C  Tenant

As you want to use the service principal in Azure Pipelines to handle Terraform resources, it is suggested to **use separate service principals for Azure AD and Azure AD B2C** as Authentication will be different for the service principal with multi-tenant account support type

Comment: how would you use multiple service principals in the same command though? If I run `terraform plan` it's going to need access to both the main AD account and the B2C tenant account.

Also is it not a security concern to have an application that's accessible by any organization managing terraform infrastructure?